# .htaccess 301 Redirection Parameter to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have migrated one of our sites from a PHP coded website to a WordPress website and I am having a problem with redirecting the old shop pages to our new shop pages.

I would like to do a 301 Redirect for this link:

```
http://www.example.com/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/product-category/corporate-gifts/
```

Everything I add does not work at all.

Currently I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# GZIP COMPRESSION
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# END GZIP COMPRESSION
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have changed my .htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products_promoDC\.php http://www.example.com/product-category/corporate-gifts? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Also an added note:

I use Yoast SEO Plugin and I see most of my Redirects are listed there and not in my .htaccess. I have tried adding the URL's in but I receive the following error code:

Possibly bad redirect.
The URL you entered returned a HTTP code different than 200(OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my own problem.

I redirected my `products_promoDC.php` to `/product-category/` so the Variable/Parameter is then only loaded behind (`/product-category/Corporate+Clothing/`) this still gave me a 404 error because of the plus (`+`) within the URL. I simply then wrote a `RewriteRule` to convert the pluses (`+`) to dashes!

```
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Category=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Subcategory=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule products_promoDC\.php product-category/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

I added a second line for my subcategories to load as well!

Working perfectly:

```
http://www.example.com/products_promoDC.php?Product_Category=Corporate+Gifts
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products_promoDC\.php\?Product_Category\=Corporate\+Gifts/(.*)$ /product-category/corporate-gifts/$1
```

If you're new to htaccess, I recommend you to use [htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it breaks my whole site (Internal Server Error) as soon as I add in the supplied code.

Comment: Also an added note: I use Yoast SEO Plugin and I see most of my Redirects are listed there and not in my .htaccess. I have tried adding the URL's in but I receive the following error code: Possibly bad redirect. The URL you entered returned a HTTP code different than 200(OK).

Comment: Again, unfortunately not. Stays on a 404 page.